# Failed to bring disk online. Access to a CIM resource was not available to the client

Tags: windows-server-2019

I am following a series of tutorials on youtube and stuck on [this part](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J9vgP08OMnw&t=496s).

When I logon to my file server as a domain user with administrator privilege, File and storage service section says this: **Online - Data retrieval failures occurred**, where it should say: **Online - Performance counters not started**. Also, when trying to bring an attached disk online it throws error: **Failed to bring disk online. Access to a CIM resource was not available to the client**.

This works if I login as the local admin of that server, so it seems like some permissions.

Comment: Okay so running Server Manager as Administrator fixes this. Could I somehow make it such that if logges in user is a part of Administrators group on Domain Controller AD then it should not have to start apps as admin?

Comment: Can you please run an administrator powershell and then try this `Get-Disk | Where-Object { $_.OperationalStatus -eq 'Offline' } | ForEach-Object { Set-Disk -Number $_.Number -IsOffline $false }` (Ensure that you are running PowerShell with administrative privileges. Right-click on PowerShell and select "Run as Administrator.")

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend doing that, that's breaking the default security the OS. Apparently there is something running which tries to bring a disk online. Check with sysinternals autoruns what is running for that user.

You could also run a scheduled task which runs an administrator powershell script, and runs a PowerShell script which check for offline disks and tries to bring them online